# How to disable a fit of content in UWP WebView on mobile device?

Tags: webview, uwp

I have a html page with a changing div block.

When new text appears in this block, the font size begins to decrease, 
so that the entire text fits in the `WebView`.

I want the font size to remain unchanged, but instead a scroll bar appears in `WebView`.

Problem is reproduce on mobile device only.

Code of Html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Problem with Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         AddText = function (v) {
           var div = document.getElementById('TextContainer');

           div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + v;
         };
      </script>
      <div style="font-size: 250%;" id="TextContainer"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="button" onClick="AddText(this.value)">
   </body>
</html>
```

Code of Xaml Page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="EvidentCalculator.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:EvidentCalculator"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WebView Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" x:Name="WebContainer"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Invoke script!" Click="BtnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
/// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded+=OnLoad;
        }

        private async void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO Need some code to load html into WebView!!!
        }

        private async void BtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await WebContainer.InvokeScriptAsync("AddText", new[] { "Some test text" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The method may solve is ViewBox.

Comment: I have tried to add `innerText` of div block. But I could not reproduce your issue. Could you please share more detail about your html page.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I added some code to explain my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. The problem is your `div` block was stretched when you added "button" text, and it did not wrap automatically. In order that the `div` block can work well, you could create the style with  `word-break:break-all`.

```
<body>
    <script>
        AddText = function (v) {
            var div = document.getElementById('TextContainer');
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + v;
        };
    </script>
    <div style="font-size: 250%;  word-break:break-all" id="TextContainer"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="button" onClick="AddText(this.value)" />
    <button id="btnClick" type="button" value="Some test" onclick="AddText(this.value)">Click Me </button>
</body>
```

If you need the text in ONE row with scroll bar in WebView and keep text font size, you could add `overflow-y:scroll` to the style.

```
<div style="font-size: 250%; overflow-y:scroll" id="TextContainer" ></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately It is not the solution that I need. I need the text in ONE row with scroll bar in WebView. (no wrap) And I was forget to add code for more accuracy reproducing my problem, sorry. Need to add VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" in WebView in  Xaml-page.

Comment: You could achieve it by adding `overflow-y:scroll` to the div style.

Comment: Have you tried the workaround above? If you still have any other question, please feel free to post here.